# UnexpectedArgumentMatcherException when calling Setup second time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I have these two tests (stripped to the bare bones to replicate the error):

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class CreditorMapperTests
    {        
        private IAbcContext _AbcContext;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _AbcContext = Substitute.For<IAbcContext>();
            _AbcContext.CompanyInfo.Returns(x => new CompanyInfo(Arg.Any<Guid>()));
        }

        [Test]
        public void A()
        {
            Creditor publishDocument = new Creditor();

            publishDocument.CompanyExternalId = _AbcContext.CompanyInfo.UniqueId;
        }

        [Test]
        public void  B()
        {
            Creditor publishDocument = new Creditor();

            publishDocument.CompanyExternalId = _AbcContext.CompanyInfo.UniqueId;
        }
    }

    public interface IAbcContext
    {        
        CompanyInfo CompanyInfo { get; }
    }

    public class CompanyInfo
    {
        public CompanyInfo(Guid uniqueId)
        {
            UniqueId = uniqueId;
        }

        public readonly Guid UniqueId;
    }

    public class Creditor
    {
        public Guid CompanyExternalId { get; set; }
    }
```

The `Setup()` for `A()` runs fine. However when `Setup()` is called for `B()`, I get this error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.UnexpectedArgumentMatcherException : Argument
>   matchers (Arg.Is, Arg.Any) should only be used in place of member
>   arguments. Do not use in a Returns() statement or anywhere else
>   outside of a member call. Correct use:
>   sub.MyMethod(Arg.Any()).Returns("hi") Incorrect use:
>   sub.MyMethod("hi").Returns(Arg.Any())

This only happens when I run both tests by running all tests in that class.
If I run `B()` by itself, the Exception is not thrown.

Why does `Setup()` for `B()` fail only when run automatically after `A()`?

(nb. both tests are identical).

I'm using NUnit v3.8.1 and NSubstitute v2.0.3

Comment: Just to be clear. You already know how to fix the problem, right? And just want to know why the exception is thrown for one and not the other?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: When I test this, A is the test that fails and B passes. So it depends on which test runs first.

Comment: All in all, do as the exception message says and DO NOT USE `Arg` in `Returns` expressions.

Comment: Required reading https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how_not_to_use_argument_matchers

Comment: @Nkosi This isn't an XY problem, I just want to know why it fails only when the tests are run in succession, not separately. Thanks for linking the article, I'll have a read.

Comment: @Nkosi After reading the article, it seems as though the exception should always be thrown, not just the second time Setup() is called.

Comment: In a perfect world yes. But this might just be an edge case of that framework and could be raised as a bug. Especially since it was not meant to be used like it is in the shown example.

Comment: I've raised a bug here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3361

Comment: Cool. Now we wait and see what comes of it.

Comment: I posted the issue in the wrong github project. Here it is in the correct project: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/587